# Problem with MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have three tables (*user*, *friends*, *posts*) and two users (*user1* and *user2*).

When *user1* adds *user2* as friend then *user1* can see the posts of *user2* just like on Facebook. But only the posts after the date when *user1* added *user2* as friend. My query is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts p JOIN friends f ON p.userid = f.friendid 
AND s.time >= f.friend_since WHERE f.myid='user1id'
```

Then it gives me all the posts about *user2* after the date since added as friend.
But problem is that it hides *user1*’s posts and shows only *user2*’s posts after added date.

*user1* should see all of its own posts and all the posts of *user2*, that *user2* has posted after the date it was added as friend.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can join the results from another query using `UNION`, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p 
JOIN friends f ON p.userid = f.friendid AND s.time >= f.friend_since
WHERE f.myid='user1id'
UNION SELECT *
    From posts p 
    WHERE p.userid='user1id'
```

Comment: i have done that but it is giving me the mysql_fetch_array error

Answer (score 0):

Get all friends ids of `user1` and then select all posts `.. WHERE ( p.userid IN ( FRIENDS_IDS ) AND s.time >= f.friend_since ) OR p.userid = USER_ID`
This way is much more faster than unions and joins in one query.

Comment: Ok, missed time part up there. But this query below should works fine.

`SELECT * FROM posts AS p LEFT JOIN friends f ON ( p.userid = f.friendid AND p.time >= f.friend_since ) OR ( f.myid = 'user1id' )`